# Is it possible to pull data using Android Debug Bridge on an N7 while soft bricked

Tags: adb, nexus-7, factory-reset, data-recovery, unbricking

I've tried countless fixes for my N7 being softbricked (No idea how it was done). I've resorted to using Android Debug Bridge, however I cannot get access to the device (device not recognized from CMD using "adb pull").

The last time the device was used it wasn't set to USB debugging mode and now that it is always stuck on the nexus loading screen I can't change the options. Right now I'm stuck on what to do from here is there anyone out there with the time to help.

The only reason why I'm so eager to not just send back the device is because I have photos on the device I cannot afford to lose. Both Google and Asus, have stated they would not recover any of the files for me and that I have to do it myself if I want them.

Alternatively Could I Wipe/factory reset then use a photo recovery software on the nexus to get the images back. Just to state, my Nexus is stock nothing modified in anyway.

Any advice would help me greatly thanks

Anya~

Comment: That's one of the reasons I would never buy a device not offering support for "external" sdcards... Have you tried to boot it into recovery? It might be accessible via ADB then. Fastboot mode (keeping vol-down pressed while switching it on) might also be worth a try (though fastboot does not give you the option to pull some files, you could e.g. (re-)flash an image in the hope to revive the device).

Comment: It's catch 22 for me because I want to do these kind of fixes for the device however the USB debugging mode isn't enabled and was never enabled before the device took a turn for the worst. If I could enable USB debugging mode from the recovery menu or somewhere then I can move onto fixing this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure whether fastboot actually requires that (never tried). You might be correct, however, that it might be needed for ADB even in recovery mode -- but even that might depend on the device and its ROM implementation...

Comment: For using fastboot _debug mode_ is not required. You can download stock image from google and unzip the file ,after that just flash boot.img after entering to fastboot mode. Fastboot flash Command is `fastboot flash boot boot.img`. But i am not 100% sure this would help your case. But just worth a try.

Comment: It's alright I found a more simple method. I just wiped/factory reset the tablet that made the nexus boot up to the welcome screen again. Then I used an image recovery software program to retrieve the photos so now I have a fixed nexus and memories back, good times. The recovery program is called Recuva.

Answer (score 1):

It's alright I found a more simple method. I just wiped/factory reset the tablet that made the nexus boot up to the welcome screen again. Then I used an image recovery software program to retrieve the photos so now I have a fixed nexus and memories back, good times. The recovery program is called Recuva. –

Comment: Could you share how you did it?